# Pandas separate string and strip

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a Pandas column contains string like this:

```
(15:38) Hello, how are you? (15:39) I am fine. (15:40) That's good.
```

I want to separate the string by the time mark so I used regex: 
`r'\(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\)'`
I only want to keep anything starting from the third time mark to the end.
So the desired output would look like:

```
(15:40) That's good.
```

If there are less than three time marks, just let that row be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `(?:(?:\(\d+:\d+\))[^\(]+){2,}(\(\d+:\d+\).*$)` to extract the last match to your pattern, along with **`extract`**

This will not work if any of the dialog has parenthesis.

***Sample DataFrame***

```
                                                text
0  (15:38) Hello, how are you? (15:39) I am fine....
```

**`extract`**

```
df.text.str.extract(r'(?:(?:\(\d+:\d+\))[^\(]+){2,}(\(\d+:\d+\).*$)')

0    (15:40) That's good.
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Currently, if there are less than three separate pieces of dialog, it will fill with `NaN`, but you can use `fillna` to replace with an empty string if you wish.

***Example with `fillna`***

```
                                                text
0  (5:40) Hello there (3:20) Goodbye (3:30) This ...
1                     (3:30) Test 2 (5:45) Last text
2                              (4:30) Foo (5:18) Bar

df.text.str.extract(r'(?:(?:\(\d+:\d+\))[^\(]+){2,}(\(\d+:\d+\).*$)').fillna('')

0    (3:30) This has 3
1
2
```

Comment: I changed the regex to (?:(?:\(\d+:\d+\))[^\(]+){1,2}(\(\d+:\d+\).*$) as what I wanted is not the last pattern but anything starting from the third one. But what if there are parenthesis in the dialog?

Comment: If there are parenthesis in the dialog, hey will be treated as the start of a match incorrectly.